# Properly format currency of mat input in angular Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to put currency pipe in the mat input field of the reactive form.
I trying to get $34.00 when I press 3 and 4 in my keyboard. The problem is when I enter 3 it becomes $3.00 and then when I type 4 it becomes $ 3.004

[image]

Here is my code

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
private fb: FormBuilder,
private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe,
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NewCheckComponent>
) { }

createUnprocessedForm() {
this.newUnprocessedForm = this.fb.group({
  checkNumber: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]],
  checkAmount: [null, [Validators.required]]
});

this.newUnprocessedForm?.valueChanges.subscribe( form => {
  if(form.checkAmount) {
    this.newUnprocessedForm.patchValue({
      checkAmount : this.currencyPipe.transform(form.checkAmount, 'USD', 'symbol')
    },{emitEvent: false});
  }
});}

 <mat-form-field class="col-md">
    <mat-label>Check Amount</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="checkAmount" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="submitted && newUnprocessedForm.get('checkAmount')!.errors?.['required']">
       Required
    </mat-error>
 </mat-form-field>
```

I have tried many variation of this but the result remains the same. Please advise where am i going wrong. I looked into so may article but all gets me the same result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That situation is happening to you because you are changing the content of the form element every single time you write on the input.

Rather than that approach, I would use a directive to add a mask to the input field.

I've used [ng2-currency-mask](https://github.com/cesarrew/ng2-currency-mask) in the past for the same purpose.

Here it seems to be an example with mat input -> https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/angular-material-input-currency-mask-exampleexample.html